# Storing results of an iteration Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to get summary statistics of pixels within a buffer region. For this, I am selecting a geo-coordinate that I am interested in, defining a 10 km radius around it and counting the number of pixels which are no data, not water and water. This is the only information stored in the monthly water history data. 
I have a question regarding the following code. I don't understand how I can store the results I get from each iteration over the separate months in the image collection named water. Any suggestions on how to store results?

```
// 1. Import water data and filter months
var gsw = ee.ImageCollection("JRC/GSW1_1/MonthlyHistory");
var water=gsw.filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-12-31');
// 2. Sample coordinate
var test=ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Geometry.Point([38.8,7.97]));
//3. Define buffer region for the coordinate: 10,000 kms  
var buffer=test.map(function(feat){
  return(feat.buffer(10000));
});
// 4. Create an empty list to store the count of pixels of no data, not water and water in each month for the same buffer region
var month=ee.List([]);
var extract=water.iterate(function(image,first){
    var image0=image.updateMask(image.select('water').eq(0));
    var image1=image.updateMask(image.select('water').eq(1));
    var image2=image.updateMask(image.select('water').eq(2));

    //5. create the count of pixels of the three categories 'nodata', 'notwater','water'.
    var reduce0=image0.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
      geometry: buffer.geometry(),
      scale: 30,
    });
    var reduce1=image1.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
      geometry: buffer.geometry(),
      scale: 30,
    });
    var reduce2=image2.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
      geometry: buffer.geometry(),
      scale: 30,
    });
    var reduce=image.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
      geometry: buffer.geometry(),
      scale: 30,
    });

    var nodata=reduce0.get('water');
    var notwater=reduce1.get('water');
    var water=reduce2.get('water');
    var total=reduce.get('water');

    return month.add(nodata, notwater,water);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Most easy would be using a `map` over the image collection and add the count of pixels as properties to each image of the collection.

```
// 4. Create an empty list to store the count of pixels of no data, not water and water in each month for the same buffer region
var extract=water.map(function(image){
    var image0=image.updateMask(image.select('water').eq(0));
    var image1=image.updateMask(image.select('water').eq(1));
    var image2=image.updateMask(image.select('water').eq(2));

    //5. create the count of pixels of the three categories 'nodata', 'notwater','water'.
    var reduce0=image0.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
      geometry: buffer.geometry(),
      scale: 30,
    });
    var reduce1=image1.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
      geometry: buffer.geometry(),
      scale: 30,
    });
    var reduce2=image2.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
      geometry: buffer.geometry(),
      scale: 30,
    });
    var reduce=image.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
      geometry: buffer.geometry(),
      scale: 30,
    });

    var nodata=reduce0.get('water');
    var notwater=reduce1.get('water');
    var water=reduce2.get('water');
    var total=reduce.get('water');

    return image.set({nodata: nodata, notwater: notwater,
                      water: water, total:total});
  });

  print(extract)
```

Comment: Thank you for this.